# What is the correct way to fetch Prometheus URL in Cloud using GoLang?

Tags: rest, go, prometheus

We have a monitoring application that runs prometheus operator. The service `prometheus-operated` is active. I want to make a REST API call to /api/v1/targets to obtain list of active and dropped prometheus targets. What is the correct way to obtain host URL of promethues using Golang?